# Geometric mean filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
I = imread("example.tif");

G = imfilter(log(I), h, 'replicate'); 
G = exp(G); 
G = G .^ (1/numel(h));
```

It gives the following error. Also, What do I need to write instead of 'h' parameter?

```
Check for incorrect argument data type or missing argument in call to function 'log'.
```

Comment: You probably need to cast your `I` to doubles. Try `I = im2double(I)`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following example with comments for illustration.

```
I = imread('example.tif'); 

% Convert the image to double.
I = rgb2gray(im2double(I));

% Create the function you want to apply to the image — a geometric mean filter.
fun = @(x) geomean(x(:));

% Apply the filter to the image.
G = nlfilter(I,[5 5],fun); 

% Display the original image and the filtered image, side-by-side.
montage({I,G})
title('Original Image (Left) and Geometric-Mean Filtered Image (Right)')
```

[image]

Comment: Note that OP’s implementation is a lot more efficient, because it uses a convolution. `nlfilter` does a function call for each output pixel, this has a lot of overhead.

Comment: Yes, `nlfilter` is slow, but as long as it is required to be executed only one time, it won't be a big deal. However, it's more flexible with functions and easy to work with.